# Trouble approaching Mancala free moves to Minimax Node

Tags: algorithm, minimax

I am coding the Minimax algorithm for playing [Mancala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala) in python. I have no trouble with the code but with the algorithm.
In Mancala you can earn a free move and I do not know how to create the Node for that game state. For minimax it is supposed that min makes a move after max does and vice-versa, but when max earns a free move, max makes two consecutive moves.
I don't know how I could implement that, because when max earn a free move, you have to choose again between different possibilities for max.

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can make a distinction between moves and plies. A move can consist of one or more plies (by earning free plies), so each player makes just one move. Although if you can get several free plies in a row then the number of possible moves can get quite big.

Comment: @maraca I was thinking for example, when a free move has been won by max, it would have just one min sucessor with the same game state and no movements. So then max can evaluate all possible moves from that min state that is the same as the one when he won the free move. What do you think?

Comment: This is also possible, but a bit dangerous. You might end up with illegal moves if you can get more free plies than maxdepth / 2. It could underestimate the moves with 2 or more plies. Also you evaluate the board at different depths then, but that is probably okay.

Comment: @maraca What is the meaning of plies? Sorry, I am not a native English speaker. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A ply (singular) or plies (plural) are sub-moves. E.g. if you have a game where you can make x actions per turn, then you can say each move consists of x plies. In Mancala a move usually consists of 1 ply, it might be a little bit confusing there, because a ply and a move usually is the same unless you earn free plies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it this way. Using a boolean, when max player for example gets a free move, you create a child min node with the same game state as before and without increasing the depth value. That min node just creates another max node with the same game state as before and without increasing the depth. That worked for me!